# Excel - Combining two cell formulas into one cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there any easier way to combine formulas into one cell other than just copy and paste the formula text?

I have a long complicated formula that I split into two distinct formulas and then combined them in a third cell. But now I want everything in one cell, one formula.

This is an over simplification but say I have: A2=A1^2; B2=B1*A1; C2=MAX(A2,B2)

But I want to switch to have: C2=MAX(A1^2,B1*A1)

Without having to go in and copy/paste each individual formula into C2.

Using a mouse or arrow keys to select just the right text to replace is obnoxious.

Comment: VBA code can easily solve your problem. But if the formulas in A and B are row-dependent only, you can build one formula by copy-paste, and then use drag down to fill all the range.

Comment: If you want to use the shown Formula without reach to Cell `C2` or `Copy & Patse` then you many try like this in **Immediate Window** `Range("C2").Formula= "=MAX(A1^2,B1*A1)`"

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use substitute() & concatenate()

```
E2  ---> '=max(
F2  ---> =SUBSTITUTE(C2,"=","")
G2  ---> ,
H2  ---> =SUBSTITUTE(FORMULATEXT(B2),"=","")
I2  ---> )
J2  ---> =CONCATENATE(E2,F2,G2,H2,I2)
```

Then.. you can copy the contents of J2 as the formula to fill in C2.

Hope it helps. ( :

Comment: Op's issue is,, `Without having to go in and copy/paste each individual formula into C2.`

Comment: noted.. I have no way of doing it via formulas.. so I suggested these to reduce the number of <select-copy-paste> from 3 to 1. I'm a noob in vba. | :